# Perl/Tk's analog of StringGrid

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I write simple Perl/Tk application and I need to view two-dimensional array as a grid like, for example, Delphi's StringGrid. But I can't find Tk widget similar to StringGrid. Is there any similar widget?

Comment: Yes, this is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a StringGrid like part. There are 2 Modules which may can be used for this. [Number 1](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk-TableMatrix/TableMatrix/Spreadsheet.pm) and [Number 2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tk/pod/Table.pod). I think Nr1 is what you are looking for.

Here is a short example of a simple use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tk;
use Tk::TableMatrix::Spreadsheet;
my $mw = Tk::MainWindow->new(-width => 380, -height => 400,);
$mw->packPropagate(0);
my %table = ();
my $t = $mw->Scrolled(
    'Spreadsheet',
    -cols => 4,
    -rows => 500,
    -width => 4,
    -titlerows => 1,
    -titlecols => 0,
    -variable => \%table,
    -selectmode => 'extended',
    -titlerows => 1,
    -titlecols => 1,
    -bg => 'white',
    -bg             =>  'white',
    -scrollbars => 'se',
);
my $l = $t->Label(-text => 'text',);
$t->set('1,2', "Name");
for( my $c = 0; $c < 500; $c++ ) {
    $t->set("$c,0", $c);
    $t->set("$c,1", $c*100);
    $t->set("$c,2", $c^17);
    $t->set("$c,3", $c/5);
}
$t->pack(-fill => 'both', -expand => 1);
$mw->MainLoop();
```

Comment: Can I block and permit changing cell's value? Can I change cols and rows' number? I can't find it in documentation, it's very poor.